How to run this integration in python
When I run the following triple integral in python, it gives me an error:

IntegrationWarning: The occurrence of roundoff error is detected, which prevents the requested tolerance from being achieved

Here is the code, it is to plot a triple integral f(t1, t2, m, k) against a variable k.
import numpy as np
import scipy.special
from scipy import integrate
from scipy.special import kn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import math
import time, sys

H = 4
ti = -H
a = 0.1

f = lambda t1, t2, m, k: (k**3 * m**3) * (1/(H * t1)) * (1/(H * t2)) * (2/k)**2

X = np.arange(0, 50, 0.1)
g = float('inf')

def F(x):
    res = np.zeros_like(x)
    for i, val in enumerate(x):
        y, err = integrate.tplquad(f, ti, a, lambda x: ti, lambda x: a,  lambda x, y: 0, lambda x, y: g, args=(val,))
        res[i] = y
    return res

plt.plot(X, F(X))
plt.title("P(k), H=2.5")
plt.xlabel("k")
plt.ylabel("P")
plt.savefig('P(k).png')
plt.show()

How can I run the code without IntegrationWarning?
Edit:
The original function that I try to integrate is:

With:



In the python file $\tilde{k}$ is m. $\Psi$ and $\phi$ are functions in t, k and m. The $\mu$ integration from(-1 to 1) is done separately and I substituted by its analytic expression to keep only in the python a triple integral.
The python file in this link:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1V7csMRZObQvdyX6NmpNXoySAJ2bKmsZ4/view?usp=drive_link
when it runs: it gives these errors:
RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars
  - 5* ( -(50*t1**2*(-16*(16 + 20*t1 + 6*t

and:
IntegrationWarning: The occurrence of roundoff error is detected, which prevents 
  the requested tolerance from being achieved.  The error may be 
  underestimated.



You could increase the requested tolerance.

@mkrieger1. How to increase the requested tolerance?

See https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.tplquad.html

You can set the absolute and relative error tolerances by passing them as parameters epsabs and epsrel to the integration function. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.tplquad.html#scipy.integrate.tplquad

What integral are you trying to do? Do you have a singular integral?

@DanNagle. Thanks. Could I ask how to avoid another Integration Warning. IntegrationWarning: The integral is probably divergent, or slowly convergent. It appears when I use another function f = lambda t1, t2, m, k: (k**3 * m**3) * (1/(H * t1)) * (1/(H * t2)) 

Could you post a picture of the exact integral in order to check boundaries are aligned. Also do you have some specific values that generate this warning, I could not reproduce it with the latest version of scipy.

@Dr phy, you appear to have 1/t1 and 1/t2 dependence and (but I'm no expert on tplquad) your integration bounds seem to encompass t1=0 and t2=0. You also appear to be integrating m**3 up to infinity. Isn't this a very singular integral? (BTW, why are you accepting an AI-generated non-answer?)

I noticed that the code also generates this error  RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars   f = lambda t1, t2, m, k :(k**3 * m**3) * (1/(H * t1)) * (1/(H * t2)) * (2/k)**2 . The integration limits of t1 and t2 is (-4.1 to ~0.1 or 0.01) and that of m is (0 to inf ) . So I wonder why this error ? and may be this error which leads to the next tolerance error . @jlandercy

@lastchance. Here is the integral that I try to run by python $\int_0^\infty \int_{-4}^{0.01} k m^3 {1 \over H t_1} ~ {1 \over H t_2} ~ dt_1~dt_2~dm$. There are many examples where python can run integrations with integration limits encompass infinity or zeros, so I wonder how this integration can run probably?

Well there are integrals with principal values /  removable singularities … and there integrals that simply don’t exist. Integrating m^3 from m=0 to m=infinity falls into the latter category. Perhaps you’d be better linking to the problem you are actually trying to address.

@lastchance. The function that I try to integrate is quiet larger than the example I mentioned. The original python file is in this link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1V7csMRZObQvdyX6NmpNXoySAJ2bKmsZ4/view?usp=drive_link . While I edit the question to  declare the function that in the linked python file. Thanks if you looked at the linked python file and see how to avoid the many Intgration Warnings .

You need a small example that has the features of your problem (your original didn’t) and reproduces the error message. Your edited post shows an integral with many opportunities for singularities: for example, a k-tilde integral with upper bound infinity, and lots of scope for division by 0 (e.g k=k_tilde, or k=0 in g_k). Start by deliberately avoiding those (e.g bring the infinite limit to a modest value, divide by something strictly bigger than 0) and see if the problem persists.
